# two imagescolumns in beamer latex

Tags: beamer, graphics, two-column

I'm doing a `beamer` presentation and I want to display the two images beside each other in one slide. So, I used the command `\columns`. But I'm keeping have the images size very small. I tried to play with widths but I cannot have the required appearance beside that, the font size is bigger than the image size!

[image]

any help to enhance the appearance?
my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{wr1(1)}\\
\ce{2 H_2O + 2O_2 -> 2H_2O} 
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{wr1(2)}\\
Here, Transtion is no longer enabled.
 \end{center}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what the required look is, but note that inside a `column`, the `\textwidth` is the width of the column, not the whole textblock on the slide. So if you want the image to have the width of the column you need e.g. `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{wr1(2)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment, inside a `column` environment, the `\textwidth` is redefined to be the width of the column itself. Hence, if you want an image to be the width of the column, then you need to use

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{filename}
```

i.e. without the `0.5` that you have in your code. Below is an example, using a slightly modified version of your code. (I don't have your images of course, so I used `example-image` from the `mwe` package.)

Note that `beamer` loads the `graphicx` package, so it's not necessary to explicitly say `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}[t] % [t] added for vertical alignment
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image} % removed 0.5

\ce{2 H_2O + 2O_2 -> 2H_2O} 
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image} % removed 0.5

Here, Transition is no longer enabled.
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]